# Interceptors and ng-bind

Tags: angularjs, angular-http-interceptors

I´m learning Interceptors. I´m “printing” on the console the results, but I would like to show them on screen like {{}} or with ng-bind. I tried but I could not do it.

Anyone could help me?

```
x.factory("inter", ["$q", function($q) {
  return {
    request: function(config) {
      console.log("Request: " + JSON.stringify(config));
      return config;
    }
  };
}]);

x.config(["$httpProvider", function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push("inter");
}]);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your code with

```
x.factory("inter", ["$q", function($q) {
  var configs = [];
  return {
    request: function(config) { 
      configs.push("Request: " + JSON.stringify(config)); 
      return config;
    },
    interceptedConfigs: configs
  };
}]);

x.config(["$httpProvider", function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push("inter");
}
```

Then, in the controller controlling the view where you want to print the configs, inject the interceptor, and expose its configs to the scope:

```
x.controller('SomeCtrl', function($scope, inter) {
  $scope.interceptedConfigs = inter.interceptedConfigs;
});
```

and then in the view of that controller:

```
{{ interceptedConfigs }}
```

Comment: awesome approach, I was wondering how to send the $scope to the interceptor, but it didn't make any sense.

Comment: @JB Nizet Thanks a lot! I also added response, and in MY case, show them with: {{ ctrl.interceptedConfigs[$index] }} YOU MADE my day!